# Breadth First Search for Directed Graph

Tags: directed-graphs

Consider the following graph
[image: image of directed graph]

I was asked to list the nodes of the graph in breath-first traversal, starting from node 0.

My result is as follow
[image: Breadth First Search for Graph]

I'm not sure about the 2 node. What do I do with nodes that connects like this to a graph and is my answer correct? If not, what is the correct answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Yep... your answer is correct (yet not unique).

Comment: @ David G. Stork, so if there's more than 1 nodes like node 2, do I just execute the same algorithm going in alphabetical order. For instance, if there was another node, node 7, that connects (points to) to node 2  will the answer then be 0 1 4 3 5 6 2 7?